# texture doesn't load properly

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I downloaded rotors_simulator and execute yosemite.world in gazebo

Following is the screenshot for it

[image: image description]

(I removed the grass plane model so it contains only yosemite.sdf in the world file)

And the following is yosemite model sdf code

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.4">
  <model name="yosemite">
    <static>true</static>
    <link name="link">
      <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
          <heightmap>
            <uri>model://yosemite/materials/textures/yosemite.png</uri>
            <size>1000 1000 125</size>
           <pos>0 0 -15</pos>
          </heightmap>
        </geometry>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>0.2</mu>
              <mu2>0.2</mu2>
            </ode>
          </friction>
        </surface>
      </collision>
      <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
          <heightmap>
            <texture>
              <diffuse>file://media/materials/textures/dirt_diffusespecular.png</diffuse>
              <normal>file://media/materials/textures/flat_normal.png</normal>
              <size>50</size>
            </texture>
            <texture>
              <diffuse>file://media/materials/textures/terrain_detail.jpg</diffuse>
              <normal>file://media/materials/textures/flat_normal.png</normal>
              <size>75</size>
            </texture>
            <texture>
              <diffuse>file://yosemite/materials/textures/texture_forest.png</diffuse>
              <normal>file://media/materials/textures/flat_normal.png</normal>
              <size>100</size>
            </texture>
            <texture>
              <diffuse>file://yosemite/materials/textures/texture_mountains.png</diffuse>
              <normal>file://media/materials/textures/flat_normal.png</normal>
              <size>50</size>
            </texture>
            <blend>
              <min_height>35</min_height>
              <fade_dist>10</fade_dist>
            </blend>
            <blend>
              <min_height>60</min_height>
              <fade_dist>10</fade_dist>
            </blend>
            <blend>
              <min_height>90</min_height>
              <fade_dist>10</fade_dist>
            </blend>
            <uri>model://yosemite/materials/textures/yosemite.png</uri>
            <size>1000 1000 125</size>
            <pos>100 0 -30</pos>
          </heightmap>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

And the texture file can be found at https://github.com/ethz-asl/rotors_simulator/tree/master/rotors_gazebo/models/yosemite/materials/textures (I can't upload it due to the maximum size limit, sorry)

So I think the former two texture file is loaded well, which are given in gazebo. On the other hand, the latter two texture file is not loaded properly, which are given by user.

How can I address this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17419/texture-doesn%27t-load-properly/) by [yjy765](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3909/yjy765/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-10-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

May be a problem with the path's that gazebo is using. For example when you use `model://` to include a file

```
<uri>model://yosemite/materials/textures/yosemite.png</uri>
```

it will look in `$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH`/yosemite/materials/textures/yosemite.png
to load the image.
Everything you include with `file://`

```
<diffuse>file://media/materials/textures/dirt_diffusespecular.png</diffuse>
```

gazebo will search in `$GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`/media/materials/textures/dirt_diffusespecular.png

Did you made sure that these path's and directories are set correct and that the png files are in the right locations? You can check the path's with

```
echo $GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH
echo $GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH
```

---

Originally posted by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) with karma: 350 on 2017-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yjy765](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3909/yjy765/) on 2017-10-05**:
Thanks!! @wentz you're right
I set $GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH but I didn't know about GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH